# 7-zip SFX executable doesn't have the full registry

Tags: windows, registry, 7zip

I have a batch file that reads a registry entry:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" /v Java7FamilyVersion
```

When I run this batch file, it's able to detect the Java installation.  However, when I package the batch into a 7-zip SFX executable and run it, JavaSoft is missing from the SOFTWARE path.

I have a feeling that the JavaSoft path is in a different hive, and that particular hive isn't being loaded when 7-zip auto-executes the extracted batch.  Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Fix?  No.  Ideas for debugging?  Yes.  Start by having your batch file create a log file in your TEMP directory, see if you can find that file.  Then use that file to store environment variables, logged-in user, current working directory, etc. until you find your problem.

Comment: I started by setting ExecuteFile="cmd.exe" in my config.txt and started debugging from the DOS commandline from there.  That's how I figured out that JavaSoft didn't exist when being ran from the SFX executable.

Comment: Why do you think that 7-zip has to load hives?  Is your batch file running as a different user?  The hive for the user who clicked the SFX is already loaded, since the time they logged in.  It's possible that there's impersonation going on.  It's more likely that there's registry redirection going on, redirection is designed for installers and SFX is often used for installers.

Comment: Or perhaps you have a 32-bit vs 64-bit problem going on.  Does WOW64Node exist?  Do the registry contents you see match the WOW64 view?  No one can debug this but you.

Comment: Process Monitor (from the SysInternals team at Microsoft) is a powerful tool for this also; it'll show you what part of the registry is actually being read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben Voigt was right, there's a 32-bit vs 64-bit problem going on.  I managed to access the Java registry with this:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" /reg:64
```

Comment: If you'd looked at environment variables like I suggested, you would have found that the batch file worked when `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64` and failed when `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64`  `ProgramFiles` variable would have shown a difference as well.